# Can I concatenate passbook information to the URL of a NFC sticker?

Tags: url, nfc, passbook

I'm trying if it's possible to redirect a mobile phone to a website URL when touching a NFC tag and passing information from a custom passbook like user name, user id, etc. to that URL as parameters or something like that. How can I know this is possible?

I've looked different apps but I haven't found anything related.

Comment: If you mean, you would like to tap a sticker and have that deliver a pass that is unique to that sticker, then yes. It's no different than creating a URL that will deliver a pass with unique information. There are an infinite number of ways you could achieve this. If you want an NFC tap to read a pass from the user's wallet, you would need to write an app to read a tag then read the wallet and append information from the user's pass to the URL. This would need to be your own app and it would be restricted to reading passes that it has permission to read (usually only passes issues by you).

Comment: @PassKit So having for example a name "Jake" and an ID "123" in a passbook (in its pass.json), having a configured URL in a NFC tag like "www.google.com", is there NO way to open a website when touching the tag with the mobile like for example "www.google.com/Jake/123"? Is it neccessary to install an app in the mobile phone to concatenate that URL and navegate to it? Thank you for the help.

Comment: You would need to write that app as such an app does not exist. It is technically possible, but the usage would be limited to passes signed by the same developer so  it would be very niche.